# Installing Ubuntu on external hard drive (boots to black screen)

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb, external-hdd

Hey everyone this is my first post here on the askUbuntu forums. I've been an avid Linux user for over a year now but by no means an expert.

The problem I'm facing is one I have not been able to solve by myself. I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on an external hard drive of mine. I don't know if this matters, but this external hard drive of mine is *actually* an old hard drive from my old Gateway laptop. Once the monitor on the Gateway laptop had burned out I simply extracted the hard drive (and checked it to make it is healthy *which it is*) and placed it in an external hard drive enclosure.

I've created an Ubuntu LiveUSB using the PendriveLinux Universal USB installer. I know the installer works because I have installed it on other systems.

I've run the Ubuntu LiveUSB and it looks like I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on the external hard drive as it has the /root directory, the swap directory, and the bootloader installed on the external drive (/dev/sdc).

When I go to boot from the external drive, all I boot into is a black screen that does nothing causing me to hard reset my laptop. No grub menu nothing. I know that my laptop is capable of booting from USB because I can boot from the LiveUSB.

I've also tried using Boot-Repair in both the LiveUSB and as its own bootable USB to repair GRUB.

Here are the results http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6960951/

Please help! All I want is run Ubuntu from the external drive, I never thought it would be so difficult.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: My laptop is running Windows 8 Pro, that was installed by upgrading from Windows 7 on a BIOS set-up. I do not have secure boot nor UEFI. The computer is a HP DV6 model. The OS that was previously on the external hard drive (where I am attempting to run Ubuntu from) was Windows 7 I believe but I've formatted the drive.

Comment: based on your pastebin post it looks like /dev/sdb is the external drive you want to boot from is this correct? Do you still have this problem?